# Fetching user details from FB in XML format

Tags: xml, facebook-fbml

Is there any method by which I can fetch an user's detail (name, UID, location, etc.) from facebook in XML format? I can get data in either json or xml from Twitter, but failed to find anything for FB . Also is there any API in FB to return only the UID if user name is given as the input?

Answer (score 0):

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/ it is deprecated, in the future use json.

Answer (score 0):

> Also is there any API in FB to return only the UID if user name is given as the input?

http://graph.facebook.com/zuck?fields=id will only return Mark Zuckerberg’s (FB username: zuck) user id – but of course, still in JSON format.